# Polly's TimeoutAsync doesn't hit onTimeoutAsync

Tags: c#, timeout, polly

I've created code as bellow:

```
var timeout = Policy.TimeoutAsync(5, TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic, (c, ts, t) =>
{
    _logger.LogInformation("TEST");
});

await timeout.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    await Task.CompletedTask;
});
```

And for unknown reason it's not hitting `_logger.LogInformation("TEST")`, but when I change `TimeoutAsync` to `Timeout` and `ExecuteAsync` to `Execute` than it's working.

Comment: Try `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));` instead of `Thread.Sleep`

Answer (score 0):

In case of Polly you can define timeout policies in many different way:

- For optimistic or pessimistic cancellation handling
- For async or sync method

#### Sync Policy + Pessimistic

```
var syncTimeoutPessimistic = Policy.Timeout(
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), 
    TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic, 
    (_, __, ___) =>
{
    "onTimeout is fired".Dump();
});

try
{
    syncTimeoutPessimistic.Execute(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5_000);
        "Decorated operation is finished".Dump();
    });
} 
catch(TimeoutRejectedException)
{
    "Timeout has kicked in".Dump();
}
```

#### Sync Policy + Optimistic

```
var syncTimeoutOptimistic = Policy.Timeout(
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), 
    TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic, 
    (_, __, ___) =>
{
    "onTimeout is fired".Dump();
});

try
{
    syncTimeoutOptimistic.Execute((ct) =>
    {
        var result = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(5_000); return Task.CompletedTask; });
        result.Wait(ct);
        "Decorated operation is finished".Dump();
    }, CancellationToken.None);
} 
catch(TimeoutRejectedException)
{
    "Timeout has kicked in".Dump();
}
```

It is more like a hack than a suggested way.

#### Async Policy + Pessimistic

```
var asyncTimeoutPessimistic = Policy.TimeoutAsync(
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), 
    TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic, 
    (_, __, ___) =>
{
    "onTimeout is fired".Dump();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
});

try
{
    await asyncTimeoutPessimistic.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(5_000);
        "Decorated operation is finished".Dump();
    });
} 
catch(TimeoutRejectedException)
{
    "Timeout has kicked in".Dump();
}
```

#### Async + Optimistic

```
var asyncTimeoutOptimistic = Policy.TimeoutAsync(
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), 
    TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic, 
    (_, __, ___) =>
{
    "onTimeout is fired".Dump();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
});

try
{
    await asyncTimeoutOptimistic.ExecuteAsync(async (ct) =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(5_000, ct);
        "Decorated operation is finished".Dump();
    }, CancellationToken.None);
} 
catch(TimeoutRejectedException)
{
    "Timeout has kicked in".Dump();
}
```

---

In all cases you should see the following output:

```
Dumping object(String)
 onTimeout is fired
Dumping object(String)
 Timeout has kicked in
```

Related dotnet fiddle link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bYLTuF

Answer (score 0):

As Fildor said, `Thread.Sleep(10000)` was the cause. Replacing it with `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))` fixed my issues.